# Create custom subscription keys for an API in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, postman, azure-api-management

I have two APIM instances in different environments (dev,test) I have generated the subscription keys (primary key and secondary key) for an API in one environment(test). I want to use the same subscription key in another environment(dev) for the same API. Is this possible?

I tried some tricks by enabling management API and setting up environmental variables in postman and was expecting to get the result but i'm getting 407 error. The url goes as follows,

https://{{serviceName}}.management.azure-api.net/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}/resourceGroups/{{resourceGroupName}}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{{serviceName}}/subscriptions/test-1?api-version=2019-01-01

Also i've tried out by using some powershell commands but that din't work. The command is as follows,

```
$apimContext = New-AzureRmApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "<RGName>" -ServiceName "<apimname>"
Set-AzureRmApiManagementSubscription -Context $apimContext -SubscriptionId "<azuresubscriptionid>" -PrimaryKey "<key1>" -SecondaryKey "<key2>" -State "Active" -Scope "Service"
```

This shows the following error:
Set-AzApiManagementSubscription:
Error Code: ResourceNotFound
Error Message: Subscription not found.
Request Id: a65db2c6-a221-49c7-b021-56tegh1234ier

Can i resolve this issue in any of those two methods?

Answer (score 0):

To create custom subscription key by using `PATCH https://{{serviceName}}.management.azure-api.net/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}/resourceGroups/{{resourceGroupName}}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{{serviceName}}/subscriptions/test-1?api-version=2019-01-01` URL, initially you need to generate SAS token. You can refer this [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/azure-api-management-rest-api-authentication#ManuallyCreateToken) for creating the SAS token either manually or programmatically.

For Manual creation navigate to below Blade in APIM instance.

[image]
[image]

**Request Body for Patch call**-

```json
{
   "properties": {
     "primaryKey":"MyKey1",
     "secondaryKey":"MyKey2"
   }
 }
```

Add the generated SAS token in header as shown below. You should get **204 No content** upon successful completion.

[image]

I can see the values has been successfully updated in APIM.

[image]

**References**-

[Assigning custom API keys in APIm – Trying to be different (mikaelsand.se)](https://www.mikaelsand.se/2020/02/assigning-custom-api-keys-in-apim/).